# Trying to add an OR statement to a Wordpress category filtering, but I get an error

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to replace the following condition with the one on line 9:

```
 if($cat->term_id === 105 OR $cat->term_id === 106) {
```

For some reason I get an error and the page doesn't show up. Here is the working code to which I want to add the condition:

```
// Essential grid logic filtering
add_filter('essgrid_modify_posts', 'eg_modify_post', 10, 2);
function eg_modify_post($posts, $grid_id) {
    $filterPosts = array();
    foreach($posts as $post) {
        $cats = get_the_terms($post['ID'], 'product_cat');
        foreach($cats as $cat) {
            // where "121" is the Category ID or "Europe"
            if($cat->term_id === 105) {
                $filterPosts[] = $post;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $filterPosts;
}
```

What is the proper way to do it? tnx

Comment: can you post the the error?

Answer (score 3):

Please use the following syntax:

```
if($cat->term_id === 105 || $cat->term_id === 106)
{
........
........
........
}
```